# JFrame not working as expected

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jpanel

I am making a small program that lets you draw lines using the arrow keys on a `JPanel`. However I am getting 2 problems. Can anyone explain what is wrong with my code?

1. The drawing does not start in the center of the `JPanel` even though the first point added is half the width and half the height.
2. The lines only draw one segment and reset to the origin making it impossible to draw.

Here is the code:

```
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;

public class MyFrame extends JFrame{
    public MyFrame(){
        super("Drawing");
        add(new LinePanel());
    }

    public static void main(String[] args){
        MyFrame f = new MyFrame();
        f.setSize(500, 500);
        f.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        f.setDefaultCloseOperation(MyFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        f.setVisible(true);
    }

    class LinePanel extends JPanel{
        private Polygon points = new Polygon(new int[]{getWidth() / 2}, new int[]{getHeight() / 2}, 1);

        public LinePanel(){
            setFocusable(true);
            addKeyListener(new KeyAdapter(){
                @Override 
                public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e){
                    if(e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_UP){
                        points.addPoint(points.xpoints[points.xpoints.length - 1], points.ypoints[points.ypoints.length - 1] - 10);
                    }else if(e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_DOWN){
                        points.addPoint(points.xpoints[points.xpoints.length - 1], points.ypoints[points.ypoints.length - 1] + 10);
                    }else if(e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT){
                        points.addPoint(points.xpoints[points.xpoints.length - 1] + 10, points.ypoints[points.ypoints.length - 1]);
                    }else if(e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_LEFT){
                        points.addPoint(points.xpoints[points.xpoints.length - 1] - 10, points.ypoints[points.ypoints.length - 1]);
                    }
                    repaint();
                }
            });
        }

        @Override
        protected void paintComponent(Graphics g){
            super.paintComponent(g);
            g.drawPolyline(points.xpoints, points.ypoints, points.npoints);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please be more specific in your title. It should be a very short description of your problem that still makes it clear what the problem is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made a few changes to your code.

1. I started the Java Swing application with a call to the SwingUtilities invokeLater method.  You should always start a Java Swing application this way.
2. I used a JFrame.  You should not extend a Swing component or any Java class unless you override one of the methods.
3. I used key bindings, so that I could use the WASD keys as well as the arrow keys.  The WASD keys are more convenient for a left handed person.
4. I used abstract actions for each of the keys, to separate the controller logic from the view logic.

Here's the working code:

```
package com.ggl.testing;

import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Point;
import java.awt.Polygon;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;

import javax.swing.AbstractAction;
import javax.swing.InputMap;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.KeyStroke;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

public class MyFrame implements Runnable {

    private JFrame frame;

    @Override
    public void run() {
        frame = new JFrame("Drawing");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        LinePanel linePanel = new LinePanel();
        setKeyBindings(linePanel);
        frame.add(linePanel);

        frame.pack();
        frame.setLocationByPlatform(true);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    private void setKeyBindings(LinePanel linePanel) {
        InputMap inputMap = linePanel
                .getInputMap(JPanel.WHEN_IN_FOCUSED_WINDOW);
        inputMap.put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke("W"), "up arrow");
        inputMap.put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke("S"), "down arrow");
        inputMap.put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke("A"), "left arrow");
        inputMap.put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke("D"), "right arrow");

        inputMap.put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke("UP"), "up arrow");
        inputMap.put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke("DOWN"), "down arrow");
        inputMap.put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke("LEFT"), "left arrow");
        inputMap.put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke("RIGHT"), "right arrow");

        inputMap = linePanel.getInputMap(JPanel.WHEN_FOCUSED);
        inputMap.put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke("UP"), "up arrow");
        inputMap.put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke("DOWN"), "down arrow");
        inputMap.put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke("LEFT"), "left arrow");
        inputMap.put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke("RIGHT"), "right arrow");

        linePanel.getActionMap().put("up arrow", new UpArrowAction(linePanel));
        linePanel.getActionMap().put("down arrow",
                new DownArrowAction(linePanel));
        linePanel.getActionMap().put("left arrow",
                new LeftArrowAction(linePanel));
        linePanel.getActionMap().put("right arrow",
                new RightArrowAction(linePanel));
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new MyFrame());
    }

    public class LinePanel extends JPanel {

        private static final long serialVersionUID = 2504617322590404776L;

        private Point lastPoint;

        private Polygon points;

        public LinePanel() {
            this.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(400, 400));
            this.lastPoint = new Point(200, 200);
            this.points = new Polygon();
            this.points.addPoint(200, 200);
        }

        public void addPoint(int x, int y) {
            lastPoint = new Point(x, y);
            points.addPoint(x, y);
        }

        public Point getPreviousPoint() {
            return lastPoint;
        }

        @Override
        protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
            super.paintComponent(g);
            g.drawPolyline(points.xpoints, points.ypoints, points.npoints);
        }
    }

    public class UpArrowAction extends AbstractAction {

        private static final long serialVersionUID = 8463453082541763265L;

        private LinePanel linePanel;

        public UpArrowAction(LinePanel linePanel) {
            this.linePanel = linePanel;
        }

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {
            Point p = linePanel.getPreviousPoint();
            p.y -= 10;
            linePanel.addPoint(p.x, p.y);
            linePanel.repaint();
        }

    }

    public class DownArrowAction extends AbstractAction {

        private static final long serialVersionUID = 3619846728122990617L;

        private LinePanel linePanel;

        public DownArrowAction(LinePanel linePanel) {
            this.linePanel = linePanel;
        }

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {
            Point p = linePanel.getPreviousPoint();
            p.y += 10;
            linePanel.addPoint(p.x, p.y);
            linePanel.repaint();
        }

    }

    public class LeftArrowAction extends AbstractAction {

        private static final long serialVersionUID = -2772213334907267331L;

        private LinePanel linePanel;

        public LeftArrowAction(LinePanel linePanel) {
            this.linePanel = linePanel;
        }

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {
            Point p = linePanel.getPreviousPoint();
            p.x -= 10;
            linePanel.addPoint(p.x, p.y);
            linePanel.repaint();
        }

    }

    public class RightArrowAction extends AbstractAction {

        private static final long serialVersionUID = 8463453082541763265L;

        private LinePanel linePanel;

        public RightArrowAction(LinePanel linePanel) {
            this.linePanel = linePanel;
        }

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {
            Point p = linePanel.getPreviousPoint();
            p.x += 10;
            linePanel.addPoint(p.x, p.y);
            linePanel.repaint();
        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try casting the `Graphics` object to `Graphics2D`

```
@Override
protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
    super.paintComponent(g);
    Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g;
    g2d.translate((int) getWidth()/2, (int) getHeight()/2); // move to center
    g.drawPolyline(points.xpoints, points.ypoints, points.npoints);
}
```

Comment: I love how snippy you are on a website created for the sole purpose of helping others. By the way, this code is relevant as I shift the drawing to the center as the OP described.